# Obtaining the Value emitted by a QInputDialog Signal

Tags: c++, qt

im working on building a GUI, wherein I have a function which will add a `QInputDialog` to to my `QGroupBox`, as seen below:

```
void QuestionBox::addDialogItem(std::function<void()> func)
{
    QInputDialog* inputDialog = new QInputDialog;
    
    inputDialog->setOption(QInputDialog::NoButtons, true);
    inputDialog->setInputMode(QInputDialog::TextInput);
    
    layout->addWidget(inputDialog);
    
    connect(inputDialog, &QInputDialog::textValueChanged, func);
}
```

As you can see, the signal `QInputDialog::textValueChanged` is connected to the function pointer `func` provided in the function arguments.

However, as per https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.13/qinputdialog.html#signals this signal also has a text value associated to it (i think?)

So, I was wondering how would I actually access the text value within the slot `func` when the `QInputDialog` emits its `textValueChanged` signal? Thanks :)

EDIT: the solution was to provide the same function signature in the slot as provided by the signal, and then connect them via function pointers i.e `connect(obj1_ptr, &signal, obj2_ptr, &slot)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include<QInputDialog>
#include<QObject>
#include<QDebug>

void fun_example(const QString & input)
{
    qDebug()<<input;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    void(* funptr )(const QString &)= fun_example;

    QInputDialog* inputDialog = new QInputDialog;
    inputDialog->setOption(QInputDialog::NoButtons, true);
    inputDialog->setInputMode(QInputDialog::TextInput);
    inputDialog->show();

    QObject::connect(inputDialog, &QInputDialog::textValueChanged,funptr);
    return a.exec();
}
```